# Let's tweak the way question lists indicate whether there's an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, unanswered-questions, question-lists

Currently in question lists and search results, we always show a green background if there are any answers, with the answer count yellow if there's an accepted answer, otherwise white. I think the visual difference is too subtle. Call me blind, but I didn't even know about it till I posted a suggestion on meta SE to make them different, and was told they already are! Also green is associated with there being an accepted answer. Let's show the answer count with *no* background when there's no accepted answer, and green background (or green tick background) when there is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [feature-request] has recently been completed. Now this is a clear visual distinction between posts having an accepted answer versus those without one.

Current screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! It does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I don't call you blind, but color blind? Choosing a color scheme that works for the most common [forms of color blindness](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/types-of-colour-blindness/) is a responsibility each graphical designer should embrace.

The lack of visual difference you notice has never occurred to me, but I can imagine it's a problem. If so, it should be taken seriously.

A few years ago I was subscribed to some computer magazine. In one of the issues someone made a big joke of this instrument:

[image]

The next issue had a furious response from a one-handed computer user, asking how else you'd press control-alt-del in his condition.

So, it's easy to ignore complaints you've never been aware of. I think that if there is any problem that makes the core UI less functional for any not too exceptional impairment or disability it should be dealt with.

Comment: *"how else you'd press control-alt-del in his condition."* Well, I'd never bag on a nicely adaptive instrument like that, but some of the more obscure boot-firmware key combinations for classic macs caused me to use two-hands-and-and-a-pen-in-the-mouth from time to time. I suppose they'd have been manageable for someone with a pianist's hands, but not with my stubby digits.